# haystack with elastic search creating one modelresult table for multiple search_indexes

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Recently am trying to shift the search feature on my site from using xapian to elasticsearch. I have in my application two search_indexes and when searching am showing results in side by side in the page.

one of the search_indexes is in accounts app, to index user model. In my code, in order to only retrieve matching query for user model, I was doing the following

```
        users_form = form_class(request.GET, searchqueryset=searchqueryset, load_all=load_all)
        users = users_form.search().order_by('date_joined').models(User, )[:8]
```

I was using .model(MODEL_NAME) but apparently this does not work in elasticsearch anymore.

I tried to view my index details on elastic search and found that both indexes are created under Index:Haystack and Type: Modelresult

Am not sure how to solve this issue, anyone faced it before?

Update (Below is my index):

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='username')
    date_joined = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_joined')
    full_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='full_name', )
    bio = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bio', null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return User

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(is_active=True, email_is_valid=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue and could solve it with filtering for the content type manually:

```
# assuming the app providing your User model is called `auth`
users = users_form.search().order_by('date_joined').filter(django_ct='auth.user')[:8]
```

Comment: @MoJ.Mughrabi: Just forgot to add you can do something like `print users.query` to see the genereated query which is useful for debugging this...